# Java: How do I round a value that is between 0 and 1 to at least 3 decimal places?

Tags: java, rounding, probability, bigdecimal, decimalformat

I'm trying to get a number when I divide 2 numbers together:

```
int wins = 3070;
int n = 10000;
double probability = wins/n;
System.out.println(probability);
```

All it prints is: 0.0

But I'm expecting it to print: 0.307

Comment: Convert either of the int to a double to do a double division(that returns a decimal value). In kotlin its done by `toDouble()`, probably its casting in java (not sure). And you can shorten it till 3 digit by string templating or by multiplying by 1000 and then truncate/round and then divide by 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Atleast one of the values (numerator or denominator) should be type casted with **double**. Integer divided by integer would result integer. If one of them would be double then  result would be upcasted to double. Try it! It should work!